# page-break-after ignored in chrome

Tags: html, css, angular

i have this extremely simple html inside an angular component which is nested with other components. The page breaks are completely ignore by chrome and insted of seeing three pages, i see just one page when i  do right click on page and print. Preview is showing only one page. It should show three pages. ( did not check IE )

```
<div style="page-break-after: always !important;"> 
    <h1>111</h1>
</div>
<div style="page-break-after: always !important;"> 
  <h1>222</h1>
</div>

<div style="page-break-after: always !important;"> 
  <h1>333</h1>
</div>
```

It seems something is preventing chrome to recognize page-break in print preview mode

Answer (score -1):

Trying using `display:block` and see if that helps.

```
@media all 
{ 
    .page-break { display:none; } 
} 

@media print 
{ 
    .page-break { display:block; page-break-before:always; } 
}
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
<div>{{item}}</div>
<div class="page-break;" ng-if="$index % 24 == 0"></div>
</div>
```